# Delete Duplicates based upon Null or Not Null values

Tags: mysql

I have a table where there are duplicate records with following attributes:

1. Primary_ID
2. Comments

Now the problem is that there are duplicate records with same primary keys but different 'Comments'.
Records exist like:

```
+------------+-----------+
| Primary_ID | Comments  |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | abc       |
|          1 | null      |
|          1 | abc       |
|          2 | asdf      |
|          3 | null      |
|          4 | abc       |
|          4 | null      |
+------------+-----------+
```

I want the query to delete records which have duplicates and comments are null.
Here is what it should look like:

```
+------------+----------+
| Primary_ID | Comments |
+------------+----------+
|          1 | abc      |
|          2 | asdf     |
|          3 | null     |
|          4 | abc      |
+------------+----------+
```

I have tried to complete this using the following query:

```
delete from myTab
  where PRIMARY_ID 
    not in
    ( SELECT distinct PRIMARY_ID, COMMENT 
    FROM myTab)
```

Comment: post what you have attempted.  this is not typically a 'do it for me ' site.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to keep 3? If no, do `DELETE FROM myTab WHERE Comments IS NULL`.

Comment: You could do something as rudimentary as [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/048a0/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM myTab
WHERE Comments IS NULL 
      OR PRIMARY_ID NOT IN(SELECT PRIMARY_ID
                            FROM myTab
                            HAVING COUNT(PRIMARY_ID)>1)
```

**EDIT:**

Replace `OR` by `AND` because it depends on what you mean by *delete records which have duplicates and comments are nul*

Comment: Wouldn't that also delete record where Primary_ID is 3?

Comment: Yes, ID 3 will be deleted (it is what you want, I think). It will delete duplicate rows and rows that have comments with NULL values. @Shahzeb

Comment: if you do not want to delte ID 3 then replace `OR` with `AND` because it depends on what you mean by *delete records which have duplicates and comments are nul* @Shahzeb